# I ask for location from the same place but I get different addresses

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I'm standing near the window of my house which is on street X. I ask for GPS location using the location manager and then I use the Geocoder class to get the street I'm on.

The first try gives me the street near the street I'm on. The second try, gives me the exact street including the building number. I'm standing in the same place but the lat/long are different. I'm using only the GPS to receive my location.

Any idea for the reason of this discrepancy and how can I make it more accurate? Does it mean I have to call the GPS twice? sometimes I do receive the correct address on the first try.

Thanks

in main activity after creating a location manager object:

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

in location listener:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(), 1);
Address address = addresses.get(0);
String addressText = String.format("%s|%s|%s",
       address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : " ",
       address.getLocality(),
       address.getCountryName());
```